# CSS - split attribute

Tags: css, attributes, background-image, linear-gradients

I have something like this:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #FFFFFF, red), 
url("http://cuteoverload.files.wordpress.com/kitteh_puddle-1312.jpg");
```

but i genereate images in other script and i want to split in two lines

```
background-image:linear-gradient(0deg, #FFFFFF, red);
background-image:url("http://cuteoverload.files.wordpress.com/kitteh_puddle-1312.jpg");
```

it is possible?

Comment: no it's not, you will simply override the first one

Answer (score 0):

The answer is NO. This is not possible.

If you assign the same CSS property multiple times, the last value will be used by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible the second line will overwrite the first one, the only way is adding all your backgrounds in one property